# declare JSP taglib directives in web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I seem to remember reading that it's possible to declare taglib directives such as:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

in web.xml. This eliminates the need to duplicate this directive in every JSP file where the taglib is used. Could someone tell me *how* these directives can be added to web.xml?

Comment: Pity, because there is a solution for this: preludes.  Using the jsp-config section's jsp-property-group element and its include-prelude child, you can designate a fragment to be included in any JSP according to your own regular expression.  You can just put any taglib directives you want in there.

Comment: This question should definitely not be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `taglib` element in web.xml serves a different purpose to the `taglib` directive which you have above.

As David said, the `taglib` directive is required on each page.

If you have many pages which use common taglibs, you can shortcut this by putting the taglib directives into an include file, and including this file each page. But no matter how you do it, the taglib directive has to be on the page somehow.

That tag you need to include on each page looks like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

If you have a custom taglib in a custom location, you can also specify a location relative to the webapp root:

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="/taglib.tld" %>
```

[Further reading on the taglib directive](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/1.2/syntaxref1211.html)

The `taglib` directive from web.xml maps tag uris to the physical location of your taglib. It is optional since JSP 2.0, as compliant containers will look in a set of standard locations to try to auto-discover the taglib: /WEB-INF and its subdirectories, /META-INF as well for JAR files.

It looks like this, in web.xml:

```
<taglib>
  <taglib-uri>
    http://www.example.com/taglib
  </taglib-uri>
  <taglib-location>
    /taglib.tld
  </taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

And the taglib is referenced in the JSP page like this (the taglib directive on each page is unavoidable!):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="http://www.example.com/taglib" %>
```

This is equivalent to the second example I gave for the taglib directive above. The biggest difference is in how you point to the taglib location.

[This page](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.TagLib) contains a bit more information.

Comment: i think its not right example it still gives error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.ImportTEI

Comment: Nice explanation.I should add here that you can add a uri tag in the tag library description file (tld file) for example `<uri>/ELFunctionTagLibrary</uri>` and use this uri in your jsp pages.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, you're slightly mistaken.  If a page uses a taglib, you have to have a taglib directive for it on the page. You could place the common taglib directives in an include file that all of your pages include with an include directive, but at compile time the taglib directive has to be there.

I prefer to NOT have the taglib elements in the web.xml, and instead have the taglib directive specify the URI value that is used in the "uri" element in the TLD that is inside the taglib jar file in your WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: What is the approach, if i am using Apache tiles. Do i need to follow the same , to include the taglib directives. I tried defining taglib directives in base template jsp. But, i am unable to get reference of them in jsp's like header , footer and other jsp which are configured with base template jsp.

Comment: Got answer for above my question link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687873/spring-and-apache-tiles-with-shared-taglib