# spring and apache tiles with shared taglib

Tags: spring, apache-tiles

I´m creating spring and apache tiles baserd application. I want to share a taglib in my parts of layout. I`ve added in my layout

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Now I want to create a foreach loop in the parts of layout but I can`t. When I added this taglib definition in the part of layout it worked. Can I add the taglib only n one place or I need to add it in every jsp file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the taglib for each jsp file.

Because tiles works after the jsp files are compiled, and the taglib definition is needed for compiling (the compiler does not know anything about tiles).

Comment: that is sad :( I`ve started using apache tiles cause i thought that I can add every shared component in one place not in all every jsp file. But thank you for help

Comment: Fixus: An solution that may help is to use c:include to include a file that contains all the definitions.

Comment: but where I use this include ? won`t it force to download more data by while view rendering ?